# Why are nonincreasing and nondecreasing sequences named this way?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When we say a sequence of sets is nondecreasing or nonincreasing, are we talking about the cardinality of the set? I understand that if $A_{n} \subset A_{n+1}\subset A_{n+2}$ then the sets get bigger and bigger and so their number of elements would not decrease. Is that all it is? What about uncountable sets?

Comment: `"When we say a sequence of sets is nondecreasing or nonincreasing, are we talking about the cardinality of the set?"`Not directly, but facts about cardinality can be inferred from monotonicity. It's irrelevant whether they are uncountable or not if you use a broader meaning of 'more elements than' than for finite sets.

Comment: The cardinalities cannot decrease, but we can have a strictly increasing sequence of sets all of the same countably infinite or uncountable cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

When we speak about a nondecreasing sequence of sets, we mean that the sets are nested: $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$ for all $n$.
The definition is by inclusion of sets, not by cardinality.
A cardinal inequality does follow from the inclusion ($|A_n|\leq|A_{n+1}|$), but this is not the definition.
In the nonincreasing case the inclusion and inequality are opposite.

It does not make any difference if the sets or some of them are uncountable; the definition works for any sets whatsoever.
Note that even if the set inclusions are strict, the cardinalities can be the same.